# Obtaining Exit Rate in Google Analytics for a single page

Tags: google-analytics

If I go to Behavior > All Pages and use the advanced filter to only include results that are "Page = SampleA.aspx" and "Exit Page = SampleA.aspx", will that give me an accurate exit rate for that page, and that page alone?

The issue I'm having trouble with is that Exit Rate is (number of exit) / (number of pageviews), and I'm grappling with confirming that those two numbers are only for "SampleA.aspx" and not for any other page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JMD, your understanding is correct :)** and you can be safe you are looking at the right number.

**It's basically the same report of the same thing, see my annotated screenshot below ([full-resolution link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWlRo.png)).**

> 1640 *Pageviews* with 31.52% *Exit rate* = 517 *Exits*

*Exit Page* dimension can be useful for setting up specific segments (just as *Landing Page*). Keep in mind however, the the scope of *Exit Page* dimension is *session* and so be careful what metrics you use.

For more detailed information I would suggest those 2 articles:

- [Aligning Hits, Sessions, Metrics, Dimensions](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/hits-sessions-metrics-dimensions-web-analytics/) by Avinash Kaushik
- [The key difference between segments and filters](http://www.analyticscanvas.com/segments-vs-filters-in-google-analytics/) by James Standed

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Understanding the differences between filter and segment really helped me out. Thanks for the additional links!